# What is a good CUDA single threaded sorting algorithm?

Tags: sorting, cuda

I have a cuda program where each thread has to sort a small array (N=49). Currently I'm using a simple heap sort algorithm from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/) like this:

```
__global__ void kernel(int N){
    ...
    double *x = new double[N];
    fillArray(x, N);
    sort(x, N);

    double y = doSomething(x, N);
    delete[] x;
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the warp divergence is large and the total amount of inactive threads in the sorting function is more than 80%, due to the conditional statements in the algorithm.

Each thread has its own array which is completely different from the next thread's array, which means that I'm almost guaranteed to hit every conditional statement in a warp with 32 threads.

My question is which sorting algorithm minimizes the warp divergence and has memory O(1), so that it is suitable for a single CUDA thread?

Most existing cuda sorting examples focus on sorting huge arrays with multiple threads and blocks, but that is not what I am looking for here.

Comment: Sorting networks are branchless and probably the most performant at small sizes, but at some point they will be out performed by a radix sort

Comment: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/median-filter-time-dimension-for-images-bad-performance-no-memory-coalescence/36103/3

Comment: If you want production grade code/performance and don't plan to merge another operation into this, you could just use [`cub::DeviceSegmentedRadixSort`](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_segmented_radix_sort.html). If you want to fuse something, [`cub::BlockRadixSort`](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/classcub_1_1_block_radix_sort.html) might still be of interest. There is a [`2_Concepts_and_Techniques/sortingNetworks`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/sortingNetworks) CUDA sample although it implements a global sort I think.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't still found a good solution, but I tried some sorting algorithms for N=49: bitonicSort, thrust::sort, insertionSort and bubbleSort. BitonicSort requires arrays with sizes of 2^k and thus the array of 49 needs some padding.
Here are some timing benchmarks of my program using these sorting algorithms, but note that they may not be representative of every usecase:

| Algorithm | Time(s) |
| --- | --- |
| heapSort | 46 |
| bitonicSort | 55 |
| thrust::sort | 80 |
| insertion sort | 48 |
| bubble sort | 55 |

The results are quite disappointing.
RadixSort would probably be fastest for integers, but I have to use doubles so I cannot use it. The sorting algorithms in Cub need auxiliary memory, which I want to avoid (because I am memory limited).

When I find something faster, I will update this answer.

Comment: Radix sort is easily modified to work on floating point numbers (CUB does that). See e.g. [this blog post](https://www.codercorner.com/RadixSortRevisited.htm) which is linked from the Wikipedia article on radix sort.

Comment: Some time ago I [played around with sorting networks](https://github.com/quxflux/sorting_network_cpp) including those ones which operate on a problem size not equal to a power of two (the fastest one hereby being [Bose Nelson Sort](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/B978072042262750020X)).
If you are willing to compile your CUDA code with `--expt-relaxed-constexpr`, you might use that implementation to sort your array data like I did for a [CUDA median filter implementation](https://github.com/quxflux/cuda_median_filter) and evaluate if it fits your performance requirements